# Outlook 2016 rules(out of office) for every tuesday

Tags: outlook

How can I set rule or use out of office in Outlook 2016 only for e.g. every Tuesday?

I am looking for **every** Tuesday. Not the next tuesday

Comment: Hi MoHo, welcome to Stackoverflow. SO is more for progamming but http://superuser.com/ may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

No, the best you can do is specify the range of OOF dates. There is no support for recurrences on either programmatic or UI level.